# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() : Yii2

Tags: php, reactjs, yii2

The error occurred in this statement `foreach ($plusone_subjects as $subject)`. The variable `$plusone_subjects` has the below data stored in it.

```
{
    "subject_name": "test",
    "maximum_marks": 100
},
{
    "subject_name": "test2",
    "maximum_marks": 200
}
```

I need to access one pair of `subject_name` and `maximum_marks` in each loop.

Comment: Just as a check, can you show the results of `var_dump($plusone_subjects);`

Comment: `string(94) "{"subject_name" : "test","maximum_marks": 100},{"subject_name" : "test2","maximum_marks": 200}"`

Comment: It looks like invalid JSON, so first fix the data (at least needs `[]` round the whole thing) and then use `json_decode()` as the loop variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `$plusone_subjects` is not valid json, you can manually change it to valid json and then convert it to an array like so:

```
$plusone_subjects = "[$plusone_subjects]"; //covert string to valid json;
$plusone_subjects = json_decode($plusone_subjects,true); //covert to array

foreach ($plusone_subjects as $subject)
{
    echo $subject["subject_name"]; 
}
```